# Refresh a screen from anywhere (react-navigation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a router with a lot of screens and nested navigators, and everything is working exactly how I want it to. I'm using redux for a lot of state throughout, but I'm not using redux for navigation state.

If something unexpected goes wrong, for example no network connection, an alert comes up. Once the alert is dismissed, there may be some missing information on the screen. I did the "pull down to refresh" thing using RefreshControl and StackActions.reset in a couple of the most common places with ScrollViews.

I suppose it's possible to write this refresh function for every single screen to re-fetch data on pull-down refresh, but it seems wrong, like I should be able to get the navigation state from anywhere and then use StackActions.reset to reset the navigation state to exactly where it was where the actions are navigations to everything in the stack using a generic refresh function. Having a bit of trouble deciphering the navigation state to be able to do this generically from anywhere though, has anyone else done something similar?

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, the generic refresh button would be what is passed to onRefresh in the RefreshControl that gets passed to every ScrollView in the application.

Comment: This question seems quite broad at the moment. Perhaps you could post a bit of code to show what you've done, what the problem is and what it should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
navigation.replace(routeName)